# Perl CPAN Module Install fails: DBD::Pg (PostgreSQL Driver) on Windows7 64 bit Strawberry Perl 5.26.1, PostgreSQL 12

Tags: postgresql, perl, installation, cpan, dbd

First logged on GitHub:
https://github.com/metacpan/metacpan-web/issues/2266

Then CPAN:
https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=131708

## 1st issue:

`cpan install DBD::Pg` fails looking for **LIBPQ.dll**

### Fix:

1. set Postgres **ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES** so CPAN/Perl could find all PostgreSQL binaries
2. Installed **MinGW** then installed **pexports** MinGW package so I could follow the [DBD::Pg README](https://metacpan.org/source/TURNSTEP/DBD-Pg-3.10.4/README) for Strawberry
3. Exported symbols from **LIBPQ.DLL** as described above

## Current Issue:

`cpan DBD::Pg` install now failing with the follow error for all exported symbols above:

`dbdimp.o:dbdimp.c:(.text+0x479): undefined reference to 'PQstatus'
<...etc...etc...>`

***Anyone know how I can get this installed and working properly so I can drive Postgres with Perl?***

Comment: Last couple of lines following the `undefined reference to` lines is: `c:/perl64/site/lib/auto/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: dbdimp.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section .da
ta'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'blib\arch\auto\DBD\Pg\Pg.dll'`

Comment: Could the installation of MinGW have spoiled something in Perl?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Windows 10
- Strawberry perl 5.30.1
- [Downloaded](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/) PostgreSQL version 12.1 for Windows x86-64
- Ran the installer. Pre Installation Summary:

  ```
  Installation Directory: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12
  Server Installation Directory: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12
  Data Directory: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data
  Database Port: 5432
  Database Superuser: postgres
  Operating System Account: NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
  Database Service: postgresql-x64-12
  Command Line Tools Installation Directory: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12
  pgAdmin4 Installation Directory: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4
  Stack Builder Installation Directory: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12
  ```
- From the command prompt:

  ```
  > cpanm DBD::Pg
  --> Working on DBD::Pg
  Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/T/TU/TURNSTEP/DBD-Pg-3.10.4.tar.gz ... OK
  Configuring DBD-Pg-3.10.4 ... OK
  Building and testing DBD-Pg-3.10.4 ... OK
  Successfully installed DBD-Pg-3.10.4 (upgraded from 3.8.0)
  1 distribution installed
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but Windows 10 ain't gonna happen...not yet, anyway.